# Python: Possible to use urlparse to parse domain from cgi bin URL

Tags: python, regex

I have the following **input string**:

```
/cgi-bin/ivw/CP/dbb_ug_sp;?r=http%3A//www.some-super-domain.de/forum/viewtopic.php%3Ff%3D2%26t%3D18564%26start%3D75&d=76756.76050130278
```

I wanted to use `urlparse()` to **get the domain**, but getting the `netloc` attribute returns an empty string in this case.

How can I extract the domain (bestcase: without www)?

**Output wanted:** some-super-domain.de

Please note: Sometimes there is **no www** in above input string!

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: some-super-domain.de

Answer (score 1):

I think `urlparse` dot give you what you want you can use this :

```
m=re.search(r'(?<=www\.)[a-zA-Z\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+',s)
print m.group(0)
```

result:

```
some-super-domain.de
```

try it [HERE](http://regex101.com/#python) !

so if you use `urlparse` the result is this :

```
s='/cgi-bin/ivw/CP/dbb_ug_sp;?r=http%3A//www.some-super-domain.de/forum/viewtopic.php%3Ff%3D2%26t%3D18564%26start%3D75&d=76756.76050130278'

from urlparse import urlparse
o = urlparse(s)
print o
```

result:

```
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='/cgi-bin/ivw/CP/dbb_ug_sp', params='', query='r=http%3A//www.some-super-domain.de/forum/viewtopic.php%3Ff%3D2%26t%3D18564%26start%3D75&d=76756.76050130278', fragment='')
```

So in this result you can access to domain with `o.query` but it isn't what you want it's contain extra character !

```
>>>print o.query
>>>r=http%3A//www.some-super-domain.de/forum/viewtopic.php%3Ff%3D2%26t%3D18564%26start%3D75&d=76756.76050130278
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code works fine :

```
from urlparse import urlparse
import urllib
url = '/cgi-bin/ivw/CP/dbb_ug_sp;?r=http%3A//www.some-super-domain.de/forum/viewtopic.php%3Ff%3D2%26t%3D18564%26start%3D75&d=76756.76050130278';
url= url[url.find('http'):]
url= urllib.unquote(url).decode('utf8')
result= urlparse(url);
domain = '{uri.netloc}'.format(uri=result)
if(domain.find('www.')!=None):
    domain=domain[4:]
print (domain);
```

Comment: That's great! What I was looking for. Any idea how to mitigate for cases when I run into this error:     return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 50: invalid continuation byte

Answer (score 0):

```
www\.(.*?)\/
```

This works.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/pP3pN1/18

Comment: working on your demo page, but ain't working in my script, e.g.: domain = re.match('^www\.(.*?)\/$', line)

Comment: @SirBenBenji You need to raw your regex string: `domain = re.match(r'^www\.(.*?)\/', line)` and remove the `$` at the end.

Comment: @vks version works. any idea how to cater for cases when www is not occuring?

Comment: @SirBenBenji can you provide a sample input

Comment: @SirBenBenji you can try \/\/(.*?)\/

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below code which uses variable length lookbehind,

```
>>> import regex
>>> s = "/cgi-bin/ivw/CP/dbb_ug_sp;?r=http%3A//www.some-super-domain.de/forum/viewtopic.php%3Ff%3D2%26t%3D18564%26start%3D75&d=76756.76050130278"""
>>> m = regex.search(r'(?<=https?[^/]*//www\.)[^/]*', s).group()
>>> m
'some-super-domain.de'
```

**OR**

```
>>> m = re.search(r'(?<=www\.)[^/]*', s).group()
>>> m
'some-super-domain.de'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import urlparse
import urllib

HTTP_PREFIX = 'http://'
URI = '/cgi-bin/ivw/CP/dbb_ug_sp;?r=http%3A//www.some-super-domain.de/forum/viewtopic.php%3Ff%3D2%26t%3D18564%26start%3D75&d=76756.76050130278'

# Unquote the HTTP quoted URI
unquoted_uri = urllib.unquote(URI)

# Parse the URI to get just the URL in the query
queryurl = HTTP_PREFIX + unquoted_uri.split(HTTP_PREFIX)[-1]

# Now you get the hostname you were looking for
parsed_hostname = urlparse.urlparse(queryurl).netloc
```